# Get all Master entities but only some Detail

Tags: nhibernate, hql

I want to get all StatoRete (Master entity) but populate Dettagli collection (details entities) with only entities that has property Done=0.
This query doesn't return StatoRete with no details with Done=0 and this is the problem.

```
Session.CreateQuery("select st from StatoRete st left join fetch st.Dettagli dett where dett.Done=0 and st.Data<:data")
.SetDateTime("data",DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(parametri.GetTempoAccorpamento()))
.SetResultTransformer(new DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer()).List<StatoRete>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for NHibernate, but Hibernate supports the `with` keyword:

```
select st from StatoRete st 
left join fetch st.Dettagli dett with dett.Done = 0
where st.Data < :data
```

Comment: doesn't work .. i get:

NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.SemanticException : with-clause not allowed on fetched associations; use filters [select st from StatoRete st left join fetch st.Dettagli dett with dett.Done=0 where st.Data<:data]